# Need jQuery Equal Height Smooth Transition to Responsive Size

Tags: jquery

How what can I do to update my jQuery to do a smooth transition from equal height **divs** to unequal height **divs** when a page is less than 768 pixels wide?

I created jQuery equal height code that is applied when a page is larger than 768 pixels wide.

However, changing the width of my page from larger than 768 pixels wide to less than 768 pixels wide I see a flicker in the page where the styles of the equal height **divs** quickly switch from a **height** style of pixels (like **height: 104px**) to **height: auto** in less than a second.

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/risingPhoenix1979/mwgs7Lex/2/

**jQuery**

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    if(windowWidth > 768) {
        group.height(tallest);
    }
    else if((windowWidth <= 768)) {
        group.css('height', 'auto');
     }
 }

 $(window).on('load resize', function() {
    equalHeight($('.sameHeight'));
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='sameHeight'><p>One<br>two<br>three<br>asdfsdafkjdsafasdffa asdfaksdfadsk asdfkadsfjdsak asdf asdfkdas sdaf sdfkdsjsdadiewruwei asdfksdfk</p></div>
<div class='sameHeight'><p>four</p></div>
<div class='sameHeight'><p>four</p></div>       
<div class='sameHeight'><p>four</p></div>
<div class='sameHeight'><p>four</p></div>
<div class='sameHeight'><p>four</p></div>
<div class='sameHeight'><p>four</p></div>
<div class='sameHeight'><p>four</p></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can not reproduce what you described above check 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/37j89a5m07bs9f9/stack.mp4?dl=0

Comment: if you know your tallest height before hand, you can use media queries rather than doing it in jquery